# How to show Video Stream Tracks from two different streams in one HTMLMediaElement (from camera and WebGL stream)

Tags: javascript, video, stream, webrtc, mediastream

I need to show video from the users camera and virtual objects created with WebGL on a web page in a single html element, probably, either `<canvas>` or `<video>`.

I can successfully get user video, it is a stream, from navigator's media devices and show it in `<video>` element.

I can successfully create virtual visual objects with WebGL and show them in a `<canvas>` element, by using other's example code here (from MDN).

I need to mix them on a single html element. How can I achieve that.

My further research shows me that there is a `captureStream()` method of `HTMLMediaElement` interface. Both `<video>` and canvas have this method. I can capture the stream from such elements and use it for something else, like attaching into another *html element* (but not into a canvas element probably) or a *WebRTC Peer Connection* as source, recording it. But this overwrites the previous stream.

Then I have found that a **stream**, called `MediaStream`, has **tracks** inside them, like *video track*s, *audio tracks* even *text tracks*. And more can be added by `addTrack` method of the `MediaStream`, and they can be gotten by `getTracks` method. I have added the **video track** from my `<canvas>` element's stream to the `<video>` elements stream, however, I can only view the original **video track** from the **user media** in the `<video>` element.

What am I missing to achieve that?

```
<html>
  <body>
    getting video stream from camera into screen
    <video autoplay></video>

    getting virtual objects into screen
    <canvas id="glcanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
  </body>
  // webgl codes that draws a rotating colored cube on html canvas webgl context
  <script src="gl-matrix.js"></script>
  <script src="webgl-demo.js"></script>

  <script>
    // getting video stream from camera into screen
    const video = document.querySelector("video"); 

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
      .then(stream => {
        let canv = document.querySelector("#glcanvas");
        let canvstrm = canv.captureStream();
        // get track from the canvas stream and add to the user media stream
        let canvstrmtrack = canvstrm.getTracks()[0]
        stream.addTrack(canvstrmtrack);
        video.srcObject = stream;
    })
  </script>


</html>
```

[Complete gist](https://gist.github.com/fselcukcan/6096e4ec23700ad3b64672951a4566ca)

Comment: What do you mean "mix them on a single html element"? What would that look like?

Comment: They would be visible together. For example while the video shows a person on the screen a virtual cube would be in front of the person in the video

Comment: Ah, you want the graphics to overlay the video, with e.g. black as transparent? Video elements can only plays one video source at a time. If you're not sending the results anywhere, you might be able to position a canvas with transparency on top of the video element using CSS.

Comment: Video elements can play only one source at a time but can that source, stream have more than one video track, which seems it can? Shouldn't it overlay then. If so why can I not see both of them? Is track adding done in a different way or its function is not ehat I think it is?

Answer (score 1):

A video element can only play a single video track at a time.

Support for this is found in the [MediaCapture spec](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#mediastreams-in-media-elements):

> Since the order in the [MediaStream](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dom-mediastream)'s [track set](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#track-set) is undefined, no requirements are put on how the [AudioTrackList](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-embedded-content.html#audiotracklist) and [VideoTrackList](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-embedded-content.html#videotracklist) is ordered

And in [HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-embedded-content.html#media-resources-with-multiple-media-tracks):

> Either zero or one video track is selected; selecting a new track while a previous one is selected will unselect the previous one.

It sounds like you expected the graphics to overlay the video, with e.g. black as transparent.

There are no good video composition tools in the web platform at the moment. About the only option is to repeatedly draw frames from the video element into a canvas, and use `canvas.captureStream`, but it is resource intensive and slow.

If you are merely doing this for playback (not recording or transmitting the result), then you might be able to achieve this effect much more cheaply by positioning a canvas with transparency on top of the video element using CSS. This approach also avoids cross-origin restrictions.

Comment: Yes that was my expectation to overlay them in one html element. Recording seems not necessary for now neither transmitting. Even transmitting can be done with it the way u said by transmitting the overlaying css etc data cleverly.I would like to show virtual images as of (or realy) they are in the locations in video, keeping themselves fixed combining compass angle, location and gyroscope orientation.